# Escape special characters and HTML in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

a customer is developing their website using Drupal and there was a feedback to ***escape/filter the special characters and escape html in user input to avoid injection vulnerabilities***.

Is there ***any drupal plugin available*** to do this ?

or

should we ***develop any server side code as part of my website*** to do this escaping functionality ? ***If so, is it PHP only or can it be in any other language ?***

Note: I am new to Drupal

Comment: What user input do you need to escape?

Comment: @useyourillusiontoo I am yet to see the actual issue, just saw this in a issue report. I thought a server side code or drupal plugin should be used in the user input forms to perform this function. I guess they require few custom escaping apart from the out of the box escaping.

Comment: I guess if the forms have been custom coded and not escaped you could look at the filter_xss() function. See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/filter_xss/7.x

Comment: what  is the "issue report."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using HTML Purifier library at http://htmlpurifier.org
For Drupal 7 there is a module that implements HTML Purifier https://www.drupal.org/project/htmlpurifier